# Periodic printing of shapes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making an application using WPF and C#. What I'm trying to do is to print a lots of shapes on a canvas with some time in between when I push a button. At the moment when I push the button, everything just pops up at once. I have tried to sleep the thread for some time between every "print" but that doesn't help, it just take longer time before everything splash up at once. What I want to achive is that the shapes pop up one at a time with lets say 0.5 seconds in between. The code is the following:

```
   private void Create_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Path f = FlowerFactory.createFlower(FlowerBP, true);
            Canvas.SetLeft(f, random.Next(0, 1650));
            Canvas.SetTop(f, random.Next(0,1000));
            DrawBoard.Children.Add(f);
        }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to, first, run the loop in a background thread so that it doesn't block the UI from updating; and second, send the UI-rendering tasks back to the UI thread.  For the first, you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and for the second, use `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```
Random random = new Random();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
        {
            Path f = FlowerFactory.createFlower(FlowerBP, true);
            Canvas.SetLeft(f, random.Next(0, 1650));
            Canvas.SetTop(f, random.Next(0,1000));
            DrawBoard.Children.Add(f);
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing, that just did it :) I am not very used with => (lambda?) but I will look into it. Thank you very much

Comment: Nice solution but Task Library is part of Framework 4.5. In same time it is possible to include it separately.

Comment: @RredCat I think you mean 4.0... I've never been on 4.5 and I'm able to use it.  Maybe you're thinking of the async / await stuff, which is 4.5?

Comment: @dbaseman Just checked - it works for 4.0. You are right. I think about async/await.

Answer (score 1):

It was bad decision to sleep your main thread that responsible for GUI.

Try to use [DispatchTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). For example:

```
DispatcherTimer m_dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
int m_count = 50;

private void Init()
{
    m_dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTick);
    m_dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
}

private void Create_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_count = 50;
    m_dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Draw your shapes here

    if(0>=--m_count)
    {
        m_dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked aswell but I did like dBasemans solution a little bit more because it let me keep my for loop in this case but I can imagine that I will use this solution later. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
...
var subscription = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)).Take(50).Subscribe(x=>CreateRandomFlower);
```